# Redis appendonly.aof file size out of control

Tags: redis

I host a Rails 5 website that uses Sidekiq to manage its background jobs. The problem I have is that regularly the appendonly.aof file grows to big that it fills that whole disk where it is saved.

It there a way to limit the size of appendonly.aof ?

My redis.conf file is pretty standard

> ########################## GENERAL
>
> daemonize yes pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid port 6379
>   tcp-backlog 511 bind 0.0.0.0
>
> timeout 0 tcp-keepalive 0
>
> loglevel notice
>
> logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
>
> databases 16
>
> ########################## SNAPSHOTTING
>
> save 900 1 save 300 10 save 60 10000 stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
>   rdbcompression yes rdbchecksum yes dbfilename dump.rdb dir
>   /var/lib/redis
>
> ########################### REPLICATION
>
> slave-serve-stale-data yes slave-read-only yes repl-diskless-sync no
>   repl-diskless-sync-delay 5 repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no slave-priority
>   100
>
> ############################ SECURITY
>   
>   ############################# LIMITS
>
> maxmemory-policy noeviction
>
> ######################## APPEND ONLY MODE
>
> appendonly yes appendfilename "appendonly.aof" appendfsync everysec
>   no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
>   auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb aof-load-truncated yes
>
> ########################## LUA SCRIPTING
>
> lua-time-limit 5000
>
> ############################ SLOW LOG
>
> slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
>
> slowlog-max-len 128
>
> ########################## LATENCY MONITOR
>
> latency-monitor-threshold 0
>
> ####################### Event notification
>
> notify-keyspace-events ""
>
> ######################### ADVANCED CONFIG
>
> hash-max-ziplist-entries 512 hash-max-ziplist-value 64
>
> list-max-ziplist-entries 512 list-max-ziplist-value 64
>
> set-max-intset-entries 512
>
> zset-max-ziplist-entries 128 zset-max-ziplist-value 64
>
> hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
>
> activerehashing yes
>
> client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0 client-output-buffer-limit
>   slave 256mb 64mb 60 client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60 hz
>   10
>
> aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes

Comment: I have this problem too, but looks like nobody knows the answer.  Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't resolve it. This is one of the reasons I switched to a hosted solution so that I don't have to deal with such issues in production.

Answer (score 10):

Refer to https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-4-keeping-data-safe-and-ensuring-performance/4-1-persistence-options/4-1-3-rewritingcompacting-append-only-files/

With `auto-aof-rewrite-percentage` and `auto-aof-rewrite-min-size` options, you should be able to have a handle on the size.

You can also execute command `BGREWRITEAOF` in your redis-cli to trigger it manually.